# If matrices $A$ and $B$ are orthogonal then $A-B$ or $A+B$ are singular

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

If $A$ and $B$ are orthogonal matrices and they have same odd row, prove that one of matrices $A+B$ and $A-B$ are singular.

I have no idea, can you help me?
I tried with $\det(A+B)(A-B)=\det(A^2-AB+BA-B^2)$, but I do not get anything.

Comment: Your title says $A-B$ _or_ $A+B$, while the body says $A-B$ _and_ $A+B$.

Comment: What do you mean with “they have same odd row”?